# Minicolor.js value not set/get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I’m using minicolor.js on a RoR webapp and i’m trying to catch and get/set the value, when enter is press.
The keypress is handled but now in my coffee scripts of my RoR app, the value is not get or set so the change is not made.

```
// Handle keypresses
.on('keydown.minicolors', '.minicolors-input', function(event) {
            var input = $(this);
            if( !input.data('minicolors-initialized') ) return;
            switch(event.keyCode || event.which) {
                case 9: // tab
                    hide();
                    break;
                case 13: // enter
                    updateFromInput(input, true);
                case 27: // esc
                    hide();
                    input.blur();
                    break;
}
```

I have an event on my script calling this method.

```
events:
    "change " : "updatePalette"

updatePalette: (e) ->
        lessname = $(this).attr('id')
        console.log($(this).val())
        value = ($(this).val())
        console.log("updatepalettelog")
        app.site.design.set(lessname, value)
        app.site.design.save({},
            success: ->
                app.view.infoToolbar.success(« Success »)
            error: ->
                app.view.infoToolbar.error(« Error »))
        app.lessvars.updateLessHashColor(lessname, value)
```

But when « enter » is pressed, it never enter in my updatePalette methode